# custom post type tag template www.abc-gifts-mall.com/recipe/tag/desserts-sweets/

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress how I can create the post template for

```
www.abc-gifts-mall.com/recipe/tag/{any-tag-name}/
```

Actually I want to show the archive of the post under given tag.

I tried  `taxonomy-recipe-tag.php` but it doesn't work for me. This is the custom post type tag and to register the tag is used the below code in functions.php

```
    register_taxonomy('recipe_tag', 'recipe', array(
    'hierarchical' => false, 
    'label' => "tags", 
    'singular_name' => "tag", 
    'rewrite' => true, 
    'query_var' => true
    )
);
```

Tags and tag-links are working fine for me. Just want to know to create the archive template for the post tag.

Thanks in advance!